# Powershell executing .exe file without the folder path

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new to powershell and I am trying to create a script that executes a .exe file.  I can execute them on my machine no problem because the folder path is hard coded.  The problem is that if I shift this script to another computer, the .exe it calls might be located in a different folder structure.  Example
My computer:
D:\Folder1\subfolder\RunMe.exe

Client computer might be
D:\RunMe\subfolder\RunMe.exe

I just need it to execute the RunMe.exe no matter where it is.  Is there a way to do this in powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# 1. Get the location of RunMe.exe
$RunMe = Get-ChildItem -Path d:\* -Include RunMe.exe -Recurse;
# 2. Invoke RunMe.exe
Start-Process -FilePath $RunMe[0].FullName -Wait -NoNewWindow;
```

Comment: Trevor, you are the man.  That worked great.  Thanks for the quick response.